# Дана строка с произвольным текстом, нужно найти топ 5 длинных слов

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Только начинаю погружаться в PHP, нашел задачу озвученную в заголовке вопроса, возможно есть готовая функция для ее решения, но я не нашел.
Написал следующий код :

```
<?php
$text = 'один одинадцать стоодинадцать тысячаодинадцать тысячастоодинадцать '.
        'десятьтысячстоодинадцать миллионстотысячстоодинадцать';
$words = explode(" ", $text);
print_r($words);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
$arr = [];
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $dlina = strlen($word)/2;
    array_push($arr, $dlina);
}
$del = max($arr);
echo '<br>Максимальное число символов - ' . max($arr);
$delel = array_search($del, $arr);
echo ' Это элемент массива под номером - '.$delel.' <b>' .$words[$delel].' </b> ';
print_r($arr);
unset($words[$delel]);
}
?>
```

Вроде как работает, но если начать переставлять слова в переменной `$text` иногда вылазит Undefined offset in line 14, проблема в `$words[$delel]`.

Еще `$dlina = strlen($word)/2`; приходится делить на 2, потому что показывает количество символов в 2 раза больше чем есть, объясните пожалуйста почему так, в гугле информации не нашел.

Помогите с решением.
Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: "$dlina = strlen($word)/2; приходится делить на 2," потому что у вас строки в UTF-8, а там один не-US-ASCII символ занимает 2 байта. Для корректной работы с такими строками нужно использовать строковые функции, начинающиеся с mb_ (MultiByte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С вашего позволения, я бы предложил более компактный вариант, с использованием функции `usort()`, которая позволяет задать собственную функции сортировки массива. С ее помощью мы можем отсортировать полученный после `explode()` массив таким образом, чтобы самые длинные слова оказались сверху. Тогда нам останется взять только первые 5 элементов массива, например, при помощи `array_slice()`

```
<?php
$text = 'один одинадцать стоодинадцать тысячаодинадцать тысячастоодинадцать '.
        'десятьтысячстоодинадцать миллионстотысячстоодинадцать';
$words = explode(" ", $text);
usort($words, function ($a, $b) {
  // return mb_strlen($a) <=> mb_strlen($b); // PHP7
  return mb_strlen($b) - mb_strlen($a);
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_slice($words, 0, 5));
```

Comment: Хм...`return mb_strlen($b)-mb_strlen($a)` вполне достаточно в компараторе :)

Comment: @PinkTux Спасибо, поправлю.